# Is there any reason to switch from MobileMe to iCloud if i'm still on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, icloud, mobileme

I use iDisk and have some Web Galleries on my MobileMe account (both features that have been siginficantly changed in iCloud), and since none of my computers run Lion (my iPad runs iOS5) I cannot sync fully with iCloud.

Is there any reason why I should switch to using iCloud now? or should I continue with the benefits of MobileMe.

Comment: MobileMe is set to be shutdown as of June 2012. Do it or later, you'll eventually have to one day. iCloud is the future. Use MM till your time is up if you need things like iDisk or Gallery.

Comment: cksum has it. Best to start the transition early so you're not pressured to do it fast at the end of MM's life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Snow Leopard, you cannot Sync Docs, you can work around to sync Calendars and Contacts.

I would stick with MobileMe as you have the iDisk.

iOS5 and iCloud does sync docs accross devioces every time you make an edit. But sadly for me (Snow Leopard) I cant sync Docs to my Mac without first uploading from a device to iWork.com which is a bit of a shoddy work arround.